# Stop position absolute child from taking parent's width

Tags: html, css

I have a div (the parent) which when hovered on, a menu will appear.

The parent is 30px X 30px.

The menu is a position absolute element which can expand upto 200px based on the content.

The problem with this is, the child doesn't expand beyond the 30px of the parent. But what I want is for it to expand to it's content and stop expanding after 200px.

Is there a different way to do this without setting a fixed width to the child?

```css
.parent {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  P
  <div class="child">
    Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hover over the parent to see the child element is taking the parent's size.

Comment: min-width instead of max-width?

Comment: Do you want smth similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9fzyuqa6/)?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The text on the child is dynamic. Sometimes it can be like 2 words. Other times it can be an entire sentence. So I can't give it min-width because for cases where there are only two or three words, it'll be too big. It's hard to balance a min-width between small and long texts.

Comment: @raina77ow Nope. The parent should remain 30px when hovered on.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the child's width to be affected by its parent, then you have to remove the `position: relative` of the parent. Look at this example:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  P
  <div class="child">
    Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to site the menu to max 200 and fill this if possible. The problem is, that the parent has 30px width, and the children is in it, so it will have 30px if you not use min-with.

The child need a parent element with larger width.
Try this modification:

```
<script>
.title {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.title:hover + .child {
  display: block;
}
</script>

<div class="parent">
<div class="title">P</div>
  <div class="child">
    Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle.
  </div>
</div>
```